# Trying to understand float switch specs

Tags: switches, phase

I have a simple (maybe dumb) question about the specifications of a Square D float SW. This is the source:

[Link to switch store](http://www.cesco.com/b2c/product/Schneider-Electric-9036GG2-Square-D-FLOAT-SW/66482)

What is the meaning of  575 Vac 1/3 Phase, 230 Vdc?

is the nominal voltage between terminals? 1/3 is from one up to 3 phases or one-third of the phase?

Thank you so much

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are asking, but the data sheet can be found [here](http://static.schneider-electric.us/docs/Machine%20Control/Pressure-Float-Vacuum%20Switches/Float%20Switches-Lever%20Operated/A-84.pdf). Table 1 on Page 2 lists all of the Electrical Ratings.

Comment: I've answered the main part of your question below. Can you ask the last question again in a new question and improve the wording or give us an example of where you have read about "summing phases" (so we can figure out what exactly you're asking about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every switch contact has a maximum voltage rating. As the contacts open an arc will form and cause some heating and, possibly, some erosion of the contact.

When switching alternating current the current alternates between a positive and negative value and will be zero 100 or 120 times per second on 50 Hz and 60 Hz supplies respectively. This helps extinguish the arc.

When switching DC we don't have any zero-crossing so the contacts have to tough-it out until the arc extinguishes. To achieve a life cycle rating similar to the AC rating the maximum voltage rating is reduced.

1/3 phase means single or three-phase. The switch has two contacts so for a single-phase motor with a live and neutral connection the live wire or both can be switched to stop the motor. A three-phase motor can be stopped by disconnecting any two of the three phases.

The nominal voltage is the voltage across the terminals when the switch is open. Usually this is the mains voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Those specs mean that the switch is capable of handling up to 575 volts AC, and can be used on single phase or three phase circuits (Although elsewhere the switch is described as DPST - I'd expect 3PST for three phase use).  The switch can also be used for up to 230 V DC.